# No Such File or Directory in CentOs 8

Tags: linux, stream, centos

Hello does anyone of you experienced 'No such File or Directory' on CentOs 8? I've been using the command ls/var/www/html and that's what it says everytime I put that command.

I'm trying to install phpipam on my CentOs 8 and everytime I use that command it says that there are no such file or directory[enter image description here]. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlle8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the path `/var/www/html/` exists? If not you can try to install phpipam like below:

```bash
sudo dnf -y install git # if git is not installed
```

```bash
$ sudo git clone –recursive https://github.com/phpipam/phpipam.git /var/www/html/phpipam
```

Comment: base on this command [/var/www/html] it says "Is a directory" what to do now?

Comment: can you clone the repo I shared above and check if it solves the issue?

Comment: Hello, thanks again. It is already working hehe :)

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer if it has solved your problem.